# How to keep the content of ListBox in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

If i want to keep the content of a textbox i do this
`TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Something`

Is there a way to do the same thing for the content of Items of a Listbox?

In my `RichTextBox3` i have the list of files in the `C:\Work` directory

I Tried this code but it's giving me The content of the last line (It's not adding the lines before)

```vb
Do Until number = RichTextBox3.Lines.Length
    Dim directory = "C:\Work\" & RichTextBox3.Lines(number)
    Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
    files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each file In files

        ListBox1.Items.Add(file)

    Next
    number = number + 1
Loop
```

Help is appreciated

Thanks to all of you

Comment: How is `number` set initially? Did you debug through your code? Because adding items to a listbox does keep the prior items.

Comment: `number` is set to `0` before the loop

Comment: Then I cannot see a problem here. Try to debug it. Maybe the paths are wrong or hit security restrictions within subpaths. You can try the listbox behavior by adding the numbers as items with `ListBox1.Items.Add(number.ToString())`. Just to see how the listbox behaves.

Comment: It's bad that you have controls named `RichTextBox3` and `ListBox1` unless it's for a quick test or demo, ALWAYS specify a meaningful, descriptive name for EVERY control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will address your stated problem but there's a serious issue with that code and I need to provide a long code snippet to address it and that won't be readable in a comment.

The `Lines` property of a `TextBox` or `RichTextBox` is not "live" data, i.e. it doesn't refer to an array stored within the object. Each time you get the property, a new array is created. You are getting `RichTextBox3.Lines` twice for every iteration of that loop, so that's obviously wrong. You also should not be adding items to the `ListBox` one by one like that. You should be creating a list of all the items first, then adding them all with a single call to `AddRange`:

```vb
Dim files As New List(Of FileInfo)

For Each line In RichTextBox3.Lines
    Dim folderPath = Path.Combine("C:\Work", line)
    Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)

    files.AddRange(folder.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
Next

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(files.ToArray())
```

If that code doesn't work as expected, you can debug it and view the contents of `files` at various stages to make sure that you are getting the files you expect. It might also be worth testing `folder.Exists` before calling `GetFiles`, unless you're absolutely sure that each line in the `RichTextBox` represents an existing folder.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
number = 0
ListBox1.items.clear()

Do Until number = RichTextBox3.Lines.Length
    Dim directory = "C:\Work\" & RichTextBox3.Lines(number)
    Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
    files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each file In files

        ListBox1.Items.Add(file)

    Next
    number = number + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Some mistake made, Code have been rectified.